# Seg fault on strcat

Tags: c, strcat

So I'm getting a seg fault in my code, and I just can't seem to figure out what is causing it. Is anyone able to catch something that I was not?

Logically I'm trying to create a char array (a string) by concatenating things on to the end, and then add it to an array of strings.

what it should end up looking like is this 'word1, word2, word3, word4, word5... etc'

The seg fault happens on `strcat(str, ", ");`

```
void save_ladder(graphNode *curNode) {

    char *str = malloc(1000 * sizeof(char));

    strcpy(str, "");
    strcat(str, curNode->word);
    strcat(str, ", ");

    graphNode *prev = curNode->prevWord;
    while (prev != NULL) {
            if (prev->prevWord != NULL) {
                strcat(str, prev->word);
                strcat(str, ", "); // SEG FAULT HAPPENS HERE
            }
            else 
                strcat(str, prev->word);

            prev = prev->prevWord;
    }

    ladders[numLadders++] = str;
}
```

gdb stacktrace:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00000000004013d1 in save_ladder (curNode=0x6420f0) at wordladder.c:150
150             strcat(str, ", ");
```

Does anyone know why this might be happening?

Comment: `sizeof(char)` is always 1. And show some more code regarding the structs and allocating memory of their contents - the problem probably lies in those.

Comment: how could it be a struct problem if the code is seg faulting on the strcat line?

'strcat(str, ", ");' has nothing to do with any of my structs.

Also, it was working in the past, and then suddenly stopped working.

Comment: Are you sure you did not use more than the 1000 characters you allocated? Might be useful to print what the string looks like just before the crash.

Comment: This is likely to be a buffer overflow. Do you expect the final string to fit in 999 characters? If so, the error must be in that you add more characters than that, and that is determined by your linked list. Hence, the structs.

Comment: Use a debugger. Look at your variables. We can't.

Comment: I would start debugging this problem by putting a breakpoint on the malloc line, and note that value. Then check, if the value of str is still the same when the error occurs. Also check, if the resulting string is less than 1000 chars long.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably a buffer overflow. Put the following code just inside your `while` loop and check if that's the case:

```
printf ("%d %d\n", strlen (str), strlen (prev->word));
```

If the sum of those two numbers gets anywhere near 1000, your buffer will probably need to be bigger.

Alternatively, if the second ever seems to be a little large or there appear to be way too many words, then either the data in your list, or the list structure itself is suspect.

In addition, there are two other points. The first is that you never need to multiply by `sizeof(char)` since that is always 1 (you should also check the return value of `malloc` as well, in case it fails).

The second is that you can simplify your string construction thus, without the `if` statement within the `while`:

```
strcpy(str, curNode->word);
graphNode *prev = curNode->prevWord;
while (prev != NULL) {
    strcat (str, ", ");
    strcat(str, prev->word);
    prev = prev->prevWord;
}
```

Comment: Yep, looks like it was a buffer overflow. The string should never have actually gotten to be that long, but somehow I deleted a '- 1' somewhere else in my code, which caused this to happen. It took me a while to find the missing - 1, but when I did the problem was solved!

And thanks for the string construction. I had been working on this project for 12 hours straight, so I was on auto pilot mode and didn't bother optimizing anything...

Answer (score 1):

I have 2 things to notice/remark/reply:

1. You are using [Schlemiel the Painter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schlemiel_the_Painter%27s_algorithm)'s algorithm: on every `strcat()`, the string collected till now is traversed again. You should consider using a "cursor pointer" which points where you currently are: replace each `strcat(str, ...)` with a `strcpy(crsr, ...)` followed by a `crsr += strlen(crsr)` in order to set it to the end of the string so far. `crsr` should be set to `str` at the start.
2. As others wrote, your code is only fit for use with up to 1000 characters. Either your structor is broken, or one of  the strings is too long. In any case, your algorithm is too unflexible. You should consider checking every string length before appending, and if it doesn't fit, `realloc()` your `str` appropriately. (Don't forget to update your `crsr` as well then.) In this case, you have no limits any longer.

   Resize your `str` at the end to `strlen(str) + 1` on order not to waste memory.

Comment: I did understand that I was traversing the char array every time I wanted to append something, but didn't know a way to get around it since I am still relatively new to C. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the buffer overflow answers.  I also agree with the code cleanup.  However, I think that maybe you should look into asprintf or snprintf.  With asprintf, you supply a char ** and it returns the location of the new string.  This is very helpful if you don't need to carefully manage the memory yourself.  This routine is also a GNU extension, so be aware.  Snprintf let's you pass a char * and length of the remaining buffer in order to determine if the rest of the formatting will fit.  This will catch the overflow.

Here is an example of using asprintf:

```
char *output = NULL;
char *last = NULL;

prev = curNode;
while (prev != NULL) {
    last = output;
    if (asprintf(&output, "%s,", prev->word) < 0) {
        break;  // error
    }
    if (last != NULL)
        free(last);
    }
    prev = prev->prevWord;
}

// remove trailing ',' here
```

Note: the code above was not tested (I am writing this on a tablet.)